# What kind of data structure do Spotify use to save and search music?

Tags: database, data-structures, spotify, sharding

I was making music application and noticed if there would be more than millions of songs, it would take a lot of time to find songs with full table scan.
What I thought at the beginning, I would try to shard data on their first Alphabet. But then it would be hard to find songs if I search songs with a word in the middle.

**Then what kind of data structure does Spotify use to save and search songs?** How do they divide database and search songs? Maybe there would be some A.I. stuffs as well, but I believe there would be some basic data structure for it.

edit)
Data Structure means that typical database use b+tree for index searching. But if we use b+tree index searching, it will have difficulties as I mentioned. 'So what kind of strategy do they use to search?' would be more proper question. Thanks.

Comment: They most likely have a sharded data store for the song content itself, and a sharded search-optimized compute cluster for metadata. This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow as it's too open-ended. You're unlikely to get an answer at the level of detail you're after.

Comment: @Welbog Thanks. As you said, I guess it's quite open-ended. Will search more by myself and have a question more in details. Have a nice day!